# PHP server COCOA client

Tags: php, objective-c, macos, cocoa, sockets

I will make a chat application for MAC. Almost all is done. The only one problem that I have right now is programming my PHP API for server (I use a free host). I use POST to send info from client to the server and  ECHO in PHP to get response from server to the client by data connection delegate. I think that this isn't the best way to do this. I have also a database wich contains contact ids, names and so on, managed from PHP... What I want is an ideea or some documentation how to manage my COCOA clients from PHP. EX: My client X wants to chat with Y, so Client X send by POST to the Server the message and who is the destination, then i want the server to send to Y the message from X.

I use NSMutableURLRequest to create the request, NSData for data to send and NSURLConnection to connect to the server.

I need anything like advices, docs, code snippets etc. I have 5 weeks since i am looking for a solution, but I found nothing to help me.

So, i have a few questions:

1. How can i send data from server without echo?
2. How can i tell to the server to send data to only one of clients.

Thank You in advance !

Comment: Check out push notifications. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction.html

Comment: Thank You for your info, but seems to not be what i am looking for...Theese things are usefull after i can send some mesages between users to handle remote notifications, but right now i can't send messages between users, because I don't know how to.

Comment: I would recommend you to read articles/books about the basics of networking between server and mobile clients before you consider to develop an app doing this.

Answer (score 2):

When user A first sends user B a message, B might not be actively running the app. (Think about how often you receive text messages while you *aren't* actively using the Messages app.) Your chat app might want some way to let user B know that a message has been sent to them, even though your app might not be currently running. [Push notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction.html) is the preferred technology for that. Once user A and user B are both running the app, you can contemplate other architectures for active chatting between them, but you may want a feature to notify a user of incoming chat messages, and you might use push notifications for that. This design consideration is more critical for iOS apps, but might be something you consider for desktop apps, too.

The next question is what is the right architecture once both A and B are simultaneously running your app and are chatting with each other. So, let's assume for a second that your design entails A sending messages to your server, and then your server sending the message to B. That first part (A sending the message to the server) is easy, but the second part (server sending message to B) does not lend itself to the traditional HTTP web service architecture. You theoretically could use push notifications for that process, too, but you might also contemplate a socket-based approach. See Wenderlich's [sockets tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3932/networking-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-create-a-socket-based-iphone-app-and-server). This is iOS focused, but the architectural/networking issues are very similar.

But regardless of what architecture (e.g. sockets) you use for the interactive chatting, you may want to use push notifications as part of the overall solution, too.

Comment: I Thank You alot again, you made a lot of sense here...I knew that tutorial. I know that I will need to use Push notifications, what I am not able to do now is doing this with PHP. In that tutorial is using Pyton as server's API, but I want it in PHP.I have a free host and I want to create an API in PHP for it and handle from there my clients. I need to know how to manage from PHP the clients. If I will not find any response to this in a week I will use your advices and I will select your response to be solution for my problem. Until then, I will looking for a solution using PHP for my server.

Comment: Sadly, PHP is just not terribly well suited for this sort of business problem. It's great for writing a web service that returns a response to a client request. But this problem begs for something more sophisticated, something that maintains an open connection for each active client, occasionally sending unsolicited data to that client (e.g. an incoming message), a process triggered by a completely different event in a different client.

Comment: Ok Rob, I understand! What you advice me to use to create the API for the server? Or, how would you do this? Only the concept is interesting me. It is not late to change my mind! Thank You.

Comment: There's a tutorial with a functioning chat server. I'm unclear why you don't start there!

Comment: Thank You and sorry for my insistence! I am starting right now.